# Nestjs create several instances of a module with parameter

Tags: nestjs

There is a module that implements a Controller, Service and a Model, that i want to re-use with a different configuration.
The module is a Service that operates in different context country. I'd like Specify a simple parameter country that will mainly change the collection name for the model in the target  database, and a routing parameter.

eg

```
@Module({
})
export class XUserModule{
    static register(country: string): DynamicModule{
        return{
            module: XUserModule,
            imports: [
                MongooseModule.forFeature(
                    [
                        { name: 'User', schema: UserSchema },
                    ],
                    dbname.fromcountry(country)
                )
            ],
            controllers: [
                XUserController
            ],
            providers: [
                XUserService,
            ],
            exports: [
                XUserService,
                MongooseModule
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Controller()
export class XUserController {
    constructor(
        private xUserService: XUserService
    ) {
    }

    @Get('COUNTRY_CODE_HERE/test')
    async test(
    ): Promise<string>{
        return 'OK'
    }
}
```

```
XUserModule.register('dz') // ...
```

My question is, how can i create such controller. To be able to forward the `country` information to the services and controllers within the module.

thanks in advance.